# How to get the XML Node's elements and properties from an XML format using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have an XML format that looks like this:

```
<Properties>
  <Property name="AllowAccess" type="ComboBox" displayName="Contracts:" default="0" tabs="1" parent="SystemUsersContainer" labelWidth="228" allowLimit="true">
    <item key="None" value="0" />
    <item key="Read Only" value="1" />
    <item key="Create, Read, and Update" value="7" />
    <item key="All" value="15" />
  </Property>
  <Property name="Allotment" type="ComboBox" displayName="Allotments:" default="0" tabs="2" parent="AllowAccess" labelWidth="228" allowLimit="true">
    <item key="None" value="0" />
    <item key="Read Only" value="1" />
    <item key="Create, Read, and Update" value="7" />
    <item key="All" value="15" />
  </Property>
</Properties>
```

Im trying to make a query to return this format:

| ID | PropertyName | PropertyType | DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AllowAccess | ComboBox | Contracts |
| 1 | Allotment | ComboBox | Allotments |
| 2 | etc | etc | etc |

The XML Format above is for ID 1.

I'm not sure how to start or what specific question to ask in Google as I usually always work on listing down the child nodes like item key, but this time, the elements on the  line are what I need to display and save in a table.

What do we call these part? Are these still elements of 1 node? - Property name="AllowAccess" type="ComboBox" displayName="Contracts:" default="0" tabs="1" parent="SystemUsersContainer" labelWidth="228" allowLimit="true"

any help is appreciated

I have tried this code from before that lists down the Item Key but it's giving me a blank

```
                    DECLARE @XML XML
                    
                    SET @XML = (SELECT XMLData FROM dbo.Properties  where ID = 1)
            
                        ;with cte as(
                                SELECT
                                    1 AS ID,
                                    T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Nodes
                                FROM @XML.nodes('Properties/Property/*') as T(C)
                            
                        )
                         SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

> What do we call these part? Are these still elements of 1 node? -
> Property name="AllowAccess" type="ComboBox" displayName="Contracts:"
> default="0" tabs="1" parent="SystemUsersContainer" labelWidth="228"
> allowLimit="true"

They are called XML attributes. We are referring to them by adding '@' in the XPath expressions and XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XMLData XML);
INSERT @tbl (XMLData) VALUES
(N'<Properties>
  <Property name="AllowAccess" type="ComboBox" displayName="Contracts:" default="0" tabs="1" parent="SystemUsersContainer" labelWidth="228" allowLimit="true">
    <item key="None" value="0" />
    <item key="Read Only" value="1" />
    <item key="Create, Read, and Update" value="7" />
    <item key="All" value="15" />
  </Property>
  <Property name="Allotment" type="ComboBox" displayName="Allotments:" default="0" tabs="2" parent="AllowAccess" labelWidth="228" allowLimit="true">
    <item key="None" value="0" />
    <item key="Read Only" value="1" />
    <item key="Create, Read, and Update" value="7" />
    <item key="All" value="15" />
  </Property>
</Properties>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('@name','VARCHAR(30)') AS PropertyName
    , c.value('@type','VARCHAR(30)') AS PropertyType
    , c.value('@displayName','VARCHAR(30)') AS DisplayName
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/Properties/Property') AS t(c)
WHERE ID = 1;
```

**Output**

| ID | PropertyName | PropertyType | DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AllowAccess | ComboBox | Contracts: |
| 1 | Allotment | ComboBox | Allotments: |

Comment: thank you! this works exactly! I'll provide a DDL statement next time to make it easier :D